# Oracle SQL - SELECT WHERE IN Last two numbers (i.e. fiscal years 2020 and 2019)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve the last two fiscal year numbers (2020 and 2019) but nothing I've tried is working. In the Oracle database, they are stored as numbers.

Could someone provide some much appreciated help?  Thanks.

```
SELECT 
   Date_FY
FROM 
   Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY
WHERE
   Date_FY IN (SELECT Date_FY
               FROM Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY
               WHERE Date_FY >= Max(Date_FY) - 1
              )
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help to provide solutions more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
   Date_FY
FROM 
   Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY
WHERE
   Date_FY >= (SELECT max(Date_FY) - 1
               FROM Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use window functions:

```
select dl.*
from (select dl.*, dense_rank() over (order by date_fy desc) as seqnum
      from Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY dl
     ) dl
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Or, if there is one row per fiscal y ear:

```
select dl.*
from Date_Lookup_Tbl_FY dl
order by date_fy desc
fetch first 2 rows only;
```